# Spring web : Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I start with Spring Web (following Spring documentation) and i have a little problem with the initialization

Every time i have the stack trace : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name."

Here are my files :

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
specified for component-scanning -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.lacunasaurus.configuration.SpringApplicationConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
    and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.lacunasaurus.configuration.SpringWebApplicationInitializer</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Start Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    Greeting : ${greeting}
</body>
</html>
```

ControllerHome

```
package com.lacunasaurus.web.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ControllerHome {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloagain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World Again, from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

Spring configuration

```
package com.lacunasaurus.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.lacunasaurus.service"})
public class SpringApplicationConfiguration {

}
```

Webinitializer

```
package com.lacunasaurus.configuration;

import     org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringApplicationConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/*"};
    }
}
```

And my webconfig

```
package com.lacunasaurus.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.lacunasaurus.web.controllers")
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

I use maven and "4.3.4.RELEASE" spring version

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.lacunasaurus.vapologie</groupId>
<artifactId>test-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Vapologie Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

and the full stack trace :

```
12-Dec-2016 23:16:35.543 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vapologie-web]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1780)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.registerDispatcherServlet(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:98)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:71)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 more

12-Dec-2016 23:16:35.544 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]     org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Erreur lors du déploiement du descripteur de configuration     C:\Users\Aurélien\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\tes-web.xml
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vapologie-web]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1780)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank for your help :)

Comment: Please post stack trace and your pom.xml

Comment: It seems you are mixing both java and xml initialization

Comment: First, thank for you help :)

I added my pom.xml and the stack trace.

@jlumietu : Yes i think you put the light on the problem but i can't find the solution on spring documentation.

Comment: @Lacunasaurus What happens when you keep only one way of initialization?

Comment: If you can help me to do it by the spring xml file it will be cool

Comment: @Nick Div : I don't know how to do. I think i need to adapt the web.xml to keep the java initialization. But what do i need to remove ?

Comment: You either use `web.xml` or a java initializer generally not both. Now both register a dispachter servlet. Just remove your web.xml and fix your java initializer

Comment: can anyone tell, out of the two ways(initializing through xml and java), which way is latest and which way is good (ease of coding & understanding the flow) in general to develop spring mvc applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a way to initialize by java code :)

In my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And i change my WebConfig to extends the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
public class VapologieWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

But now i have warnings because spring can't redirect me to my view :(

```
 [2016-12-13 03:38:10,170] Artifact test-web:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:12.283 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:12.523 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:12.672 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 13 15:38:12 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:12.782 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class com.lacunasaurus.test.configuration.SpringApplicationConfiguration]
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:13.213 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<init> JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:13.350 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 826 ms
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:13.363 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:13.371 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Dec 13 15:38:13 CET 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:13.373 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class com.lacunasaurus.test.configuration.testWebConfig]
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:13.568 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<init> JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:14.108 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.lacunasaurus.test.web.controllers.ControllerHome.sayHello(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:14.110 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/helloagain],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.lacunasaurus.test.web.controllers.ControllerHome.sayHelloAgain(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:14.167 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Dec 13 15:38:13 CET 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:14.436 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1072 ms
    [2016-12-13 03:38:14,456] Artifact test-web:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
    [2016-12-13 03:38:14,456] Artifact test-web:war exploded: Deploy took 4 286 milliseconds
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:14.865 AVERTISSEMENT [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/WEB-INF/views/home.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:15.785 AVERTISSEMENT [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/WEB-INF/views/home.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:19.982 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire D:\Serveurs\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\manager de l'application web
    13-Dec-2016 15:38:20.086 INFOS [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Serveurs\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\manager has finished in 103 ms
```

----------------- EDIT ------------------------

I found the solution !

In full java configuration, the web config class need to implement the servlet handling method to activate the configurer

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

Now I can show my home page :)

Thanks to everyone who help me to find the solution